# android studio error when i want install sdk

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android Studio, but the first task is to show me the necessary prerequisites to download, [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBQQK.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66F5V.jpg)nothing is displayed and the error "the Android"
SDK location cannot be at the file system root". No matter what I try to edit, there is no change and in the end I always get the error "Requierd Component Missing" and finally it gives the error "SDK emulator directory is missing" and I can use I don't have the Android Studio software from the Android emulator. I would be grateful if you could tell me an existing solution.
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAXgm.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqUJW.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep7BP.jpg)

i try all of ways that were in internet like youtube videos or blogs but poroblem didnt solved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are facing some issues with the Android Studio installation and configuration. Let's try to troubleshoot the problem step by step:

SDK Location Issue:

Go to the "Welcome to Android Studio" window.
Click on "Configure" in the bottom-right corner.
Choose "SDK Manager."
Check the "Android SDK Location" path. Make sure it's not at the file system root.
If the path is correct, try setting it to a different folder and see if the issue persists.
SDK Components Issue:

In the SDK Manager, go to the "SDK Platforms" tab.
Make sure that you have the necessary platforms installed (Android versions) for your project.
Switch to the "SDK Tools" tab and ensure that "Android Emulator" and "Intel HAXM" (if you're using an Intel-based system) are installed.
Permissions and Firewall:

Ensure that the folder where you have installed Android Studio has the necessary read and write permissions.
Check your firewall settings to ensure that Android Studio has the required permissions.
Environment Variables:

Check if the ANDROID_HOME and Path environment variables are set correctly.
ANDROID_HOME: Should point to the SDK directory.
Path: Should include the tools and platform-tools directories within the SDK directory.
Reinstall Android Studio:

If the issue persists, consider uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling it. Make sure to follow the installation instructions carefully.
Use the Command Line:

Open a command prompt or terminal and navigate to the Android SDK tools/bin directory.
Run the command sdkmanager --list to see the available packages. This can help identify if there are any issues with the SDK installation.
Check System Requirements:

Ensure that your system meets the hardware and software requirements for running Android Studio and the emulator.
Check for Updates:

Make sure you are using the latest version of Android Studio. Check for updates and install them if available.
After trying these steps, if the issue persists, please provide more details about your operating system, Android Studio version, and any specific error messages you encounter during the process.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073